# How to find amortized complexity for insertion & deletion of element in stack of stacks?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, amortized-analysis

Recently, I went to an interview and interviewer asked me this question.

There are k+1 stacks of sizes `1, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, ...,2^k`. Let us call them `stack 1, stack 2, ... stack k+1` respectively. When `insert(x)` is called the element is inserted into first stack, that is stack of size 1. If that stack is full then the element of that stack is moved to next stack and then element is inserted into first stack. It is similar to pipe operation. Stack 1 pushes element to stack 2, stack 2 to stack 3 and so on. If all the stacks are full then we throw an error stating stack overflow. There is another operation, delete(x). It deletes x from the stack of stacks. So, if x is not the topmost element, that is it is not present in stack 1 then we pop element from it and then shift the elements and then again try to pop until we find the element and delete it. What is the amortized complexity for insertion & deletion of this implementation?

**Edit 1**: To show how insertion and deletion works.
Let's say there are 2 stacks, stack 1 and stack 2 of size 2^0 & 2^1 respectively.
**Iteration 0**: Stack 1 -> {}, Stack 2 -> {}
**Iteration 1**: Insert(1). Stack 1 -> {1}, Stack 2 -> {}, top -> 1
**Iteration 2**: Insert(2). Stack 1 -> {2}, Stack 2 -> {1}, top -> 2
**Iteration 3**: Insert(3). Stack 1 -> {3}, Stack 2 -> {2,1}, top -> 3
**Iteration 4**: Insert(4). Overflow exception. Stack 1 -> {3}, Stack 2 -> {2,1}, top -> 3
**Iteration 5**: delete(2).

- We pop 3, as 2!=3 and continue. Stack 1 -> {2}, Stack 2 -> {1}, top -> 2
- We pop 2 and return. Stack 1 -> {1}, Stack 2 -> {}, top -> 1
  **Iteration 6**: Insert(4). Stack 1 -> {4}, Stack 2 -> {1}, top -> 3
  Hope both operations are clear now :)

I tried my level best and could tell only worst case time complexity, which is `1+2^1+2^2+..+2^k` (geometric progression sum). I'm not looking for worst case time complexity. I couldn't even reach amortized complexity. Can anyone help in understanding how to calculate amortized complexity for this problem?

Comment: If you don't know immediately what `1+2^1+2^2+..+2^k` sums to, you probably need to study some more. Anyway, it is not clear how elements are moved when the stack is full. Do you move all of them on the next stack, or just one?

Comment: Consider: Right after you insert an element leading you to dump stack `n`, what must all the stacks below it look like? How often do you dump stack `n`? What, therefore, is the amortized per-insertion cost assigned to stack `n`?

Comment: @n.m. I know how to solve geometric sum! Please read question properly. I asked for asymptotic complexity but not worst time complexity!! That sum results in worst case time complexity. Anyways, we shift all the elements one-by-one (similar to inserting element in array in a given index would result in shifting all elements).

Comment: @Sneftel what do you mean by dump stack n? We don't delete any stack, if all the stacks are full then we throw error message. Edited question to show how insertion will go.

Comment: I trust you know how to do a sum. This is not a question of what you know, but rather of what you actually do. If I understand you correctly (I'm not sure I do), when you have N elements in your data structure and you insert another element, in the worst case you will have to shift each existing element exactly once. That's O(N) asymptotic complexity. Do you want to determine the amortized complexity?

Comment: @Abhishek By "dump" I mean move to the next stack up.

Comment: @Abhishek Incidentally, have you studied the amortized complexity of exponentially-resized dynamic arrays (e.g. `std::vector`)? It's not exactly the same situation, but it might help you understand what's going on here.

Comment: @n.m. Yup, I need to find amortized complexity.  Sorry for the confusion :| I got confused with both notations.

Comment: @Sneftel Added the insert & delete operations logic :) I did study about amortized complexity. But not able to work this out, hence asked the question here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, OK. I see. So when you have inserted N=((2^k+1)-1) elements in (k+1) stacks, 1 element didn't move at all, 2 elements have moved 1 place, 4 elements have moved 2 places, ..., and 2^k elements have moved k places. So you need to find the sum `0*1 +  1*2 + 2*4 + 3*8 + ... k*2^k` and then divide it by (2^(k+1)-1) to obtain number of operations per element. This is less than k, but more than k/2 (in fact it's almost exactly k-1), so the asymptotic amortized complexity is O(log N).

Comment: @n.m. What about delete? Same thing, right?

Comment: Delete is insert in reverse, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

The most common tool for amortized analysis is the "potential method", which you can Wikipedia.

I'm no good at programming, though. Let's talk about religion instead. Let's talk about Hell.

Hell consists of `k` concentric rings, with moats separating the rings. The only way to get across a moat from one level to the next is to hire the ferryman... but the ferryman will want a gold coin in return. There's no way to obtain gold in Hell, of course; whatever you're buried with, that's what you can spend.(Entering the first ring of Hell also takes a coin, BTW.)

Interestingly, the rules for the rings of Hell are the same as the rules for your stacks. Each ring is twice as large as the one before it (try not to think about the geometry of this), and whenever a ring gets full and someone wants to move into it, first someone in that ring has to hire the ferryman to take them to the next ring.

Oddly enough, there's only one ferryman in all of Hell, and his boat only seats one; he magically materializes in whichever moat he's being hired for, and spends one minute ferrying the person who hired him. So only one person is being ferried at a time.

This means that only one gold coin is being spent per minute, in all of Hell. And it means that if someone new wants to enter Hell, and the first several rings are all full, it's going to take many minutes before the ferryman can take him into Hell.

Hell's empty right now, but 1023 people who talk in the movies just died, so it's about to fill up with 1023 people. They'll fill up the first 9 circles with 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, and 512 people.

1. How many coins should each person who will end up in the 512-ring be buried with? What about each person who will end up in the 256-ring?
2. How many coins, total, should be used for the mass burial?
3. How long is it going to take for the ferryman to complete ferrying everybody into place?
4. On average, how long will each person have to wait before entering Hell?
5. What's the amortized complexity of `insert`?

Comment: Nice illustration :) But there is one issue, person is not chosen at random (4th para last line). The last person is chosen to go to next ring. BTW, I understood @n.m.'s explanation for amortized complexity and looks correct :)

Comment: @Abhishek it doesn't actually matter to the analysis, but I've taken it out.